# Programmatically open a text file in a web browser

Tags: c#

I am using C# and I wanna know how to programmatically open a txt file, but not in notepad which you can do by

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\textfile.txt");
```

I want to open up a text file, except in a browser. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Uh... Just provide it to the browser as input.  Do you also want editing capability?

Comment: Have you googled a little? There will be definitely something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a specific browser in mind then you could presumably start the browser process and pass the text file as an argument to that process.

Let's say you wanted internet explorer..

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"iexplore.exe", "\"C:\\textfile.txt\"");
```

Incidentally, here's a nice discussion on the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) documentation page on MSDN which deals with pretty much your exact issue.

Of course, things get more interesting if instead of hard-coding which browser to start you wanted to query the operating system for the user's default browser..

If that's what you want to do then you can get the path for the default browser by querying the Windows Registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command` and use that as the full path to your process when calling `Process.Start(..)`